# grayscale images not loading using hugging face and ViT

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, huggingface-datasets, vision-transformer

I am have an images dataset in `grayscale` format. Now i want to classify it using Vision transformers and hugging face. ***The dataset is in google drive but the problem is that i cannot read the images.*** What would be the possible reasons? I use the following code to read the image.

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("ImageFolder", data_dir="/content/Xray8_New_DataSet")
```

Images reading from google drive using ViT and Hugging face.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the spelling. The dataset builder name is lowercased `imagefolder`:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
d = load_dataset("imagefolder", data_dir="/home/cronoik/downloads/bla/")
```